# Bounding size of group by number of generators, order of elements, and nilpotency class (Restricted Burnside's)

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, nilpotent-groups

I have been looking at some papers on the "restricted Burnside problem". On page 4 of Vaughan-Lee and Zelmanov's survey, "[Bounds in the restricted Burnside problem](https://doi.org/10.1017/S144678870000121X)", I think they implicitly are invoking the claim that:

> If $G$ is a Lie algebra over $\Bbb{F}_p$ with nilpotency class $C$, generated by elements $g_1,\dotsc,g_m$, then $\lvert G\rvert \le p^{m^C}$.

How does one prove this claim? Is there a nice combinatorial reason for this (I want to guess that this translates to a nice bound on the dimension of $G$)?

Comment: The $k$th term of the lower central series modulo the $(k+1)$th term is generated by the left-normed commutators in $g_1, \dots, g_m$ of weight $k$, of which there are at most $m^{k-1}(m-1)$ for $k > 1$. Now just sum a geometric series and do some estimation, I think. It's obvious it should be $O(m^C)$ anyway.

Comment: ah, okay, so morally $G$ bijects to things generated by words of length $\le C$ in the original generators. okay, that matched my vague hunch, glad to know!

Comment: Do you really mean that $G$ is a Lie *algebra*, not a Lie *group*?  (Also, physical page 4 is logical page 264.)

Comment: @LSpice Well he refers to the order $|G|$, so Lie algebra makes sense. It would also make sense to assume $G$ is a finite $p$-group. It hardly makes a difference.

Comment: @SeanEberhard, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1156356), $\lvert G\rvert$ also makes sense for a Lie group $G$ over $\mathbb F_p$, in the sense of the group $\mathbb G(\mathbb F_p)$ of rational points of an affine algebraic $\mathbb F_p$-group $\mathbb G$.  But I don't even know enough about the question to see this claim in either form on p. 4 = p. 264, so possibly my reading is absurd in context.  (OP's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1156337), which I hadn't noticed, related to your [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/447534) suggests that it probably is.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting my [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/447519/bounding-size-of-group-by-number-of-generators-order-of-elements-and-nilpotenc#comment1156329_447519) into an answer:

Let $G = G_1 \ge G_2 \ge \cdots$ be the lower central series. Then $G_k/G_{k+1}$ is spanned by the left-normed commutators $[x_1, \dotsc, x_k]$ with $x_1, \dotsc, x_k \in \{g_1, \dotsc, g_m\}$, of which there are at most $m^{k-1}(m-1)$ nontrivial for $k > 1$ (since $x_1 \ne x_2$). Therefore
$$\dim G \le m + \sum_{k=2}^C m^{k-1}(m-1) = m^C.$$

This bound is not sharp. For the free Lie algebra, $G_k/G_{k+1}$ has a basis given by the basic commutators, and the number of these is given by [*Witt's formula*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Lie_algebra#Universal_enveloping_algebra):
$$\dim G_k/G_{k+1} = \frac1k \sum_{d \mid k} \mu(d) m^{k/d}.$$